# Using the Java Class object in boilerplate code

Tags: java, boilerplate

On occasion, as much as I try to avoid it, I do generate a fair amount of boilerplate code in my programming. I've been told that the Java Class object can be used to get around boilerplate code, but I don't currently see how.

When I say boilerplate code, I'm referring to the term used to refer to text that is reused again and again, with slight modification.

```
public Map<String, Boolean> loadBooleanTags(File in)
{
// Code that extracts boolean tags
}
```

Now, suppose, you then want to load int tags, where the files are in the exact same format, but you want the data structure to be a `Map<String, Integer>`. The only way I can think of handling this is like so:

```
public Map<String, Integer> loadIntegerTags(File in)
{
// Code that extracts integer tags
}
```

Essentially, I copy and past the boolean method, but I make it parse an Integer instead. What are some better ways to handle this? Ideally, I'd like to have one method that outputs a map with the correct generics.

Comment: sounds very puzzling... you do program in Java but you find yourself googling for "Java Class"? assuming it's me who is missing something, can you post a few code snippets to illustrate the problem you're dealing with?

Comment: Please define "boilerplate code"

Comment: Are you asking about reflection?

Comment: Ask whoever told you that for clarification and references. You will never find anything useful googling for "Java Class" :)

Comment: The Class object is used to represent classes and interfaces in a running Java Application. It was added in Java 5, and I've honestly never used it too much. So, I wanted to know if it could help in boilerplate code, where boilerplate code is defined as text that is reused with slight modifications. I think I asked the wrong question. Feel free to downvote this question if you guys feel it's appropriate.

Comment: No. The Class object was added in Java 1.0, not Java 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.  First of all, `Class` has been around since Java 1.  Second, I think this is the pattern you're looking for:

```
public abstract class GenericMapFactory<T>
{
    public Map<String,T> makeMap(File in) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException
    {
        Map<String,T> result = new HashMap<String,T>();
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
        String line = null;
        while ((line=rdr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String key  = "" /* something meaningful for your application */; 
            T      item = parse(line);
            result.put(key, item);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract T parse(String line);
}
```

For every variation you need you provide a specialization, for example:

```
public static class IntMapFactory extends GenericMapFactory<Integer>
{
    @Override
    protected Integer parse(String line)
    {
        Integer result = null; 
        // parse the line, setting the value of result
        return result;
    }
}
```

All the 'boilerplate' code is factored out into a generic superclass and only the type-specific code needs to be written.  You use it as follows:

```
File in = ...
Map<String,Integer> msi = new IntMapFactory().makeMap(in);
```